# jQuery - How to resequence Form Elements and Table Rows

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Sorry for so many questions on jQuery. It's my first few days writing jQuery, and I'm still unfamiliar with it. Thank you for the communities' help so far.

Here's a screenshot of my form.

[image: DynamicForm]

The above table's rows can be added using the "Add Course" Button. When Add Course is clicked, another row being generated, and the form input names will also have a number track. The following are the codes.

```
var counterforappending = 1;
var counterforajax = 1;

function addARNBSCourseRow()        
   tablerow = "<tr>";
   tablerow += "<td><select name='NBSCourse" + counterforappending + "'></select></td>";
   tablerow += "<td><select name='NBSCourseType" + counterforappending + "'><option value='Core' selected='selected'>Core</option>";
  //Other codes...
  </select></td>";
   tablerow += "<td><select name='NBSIndexNo" + counterforappending + "' class='IndexNo'></select></td>";


//--Other Codes--
counterforappending++;
```

}

"counterforappending" is a counter to keep track of the current row number which will be created when the "Add Course" button is entered: the second rows' select name will be called 'NBScourse2. The number will be incremental (NBSCourse3, NBSCourse4...)

I also have a script to delete the row when "Remove Course" is selected. The problem: if I delete a row in between (Example, Row 3, out of 5 rows), the sequence of the rows will not following anymore (Remaining 1,2,4,5). This will be a problem when I collect data with my form handler later on, as I'll have a hidden field telling me how many rows to expect, but having no reference to the form element anymore (NBSCourse3 will be gone.)

Is there a good way to refresh the sequence of the rows, and rename the individual element to reflect the correct number sequence.

I wouldn't be able to use the [] method, because that's in PHP, and I'm coding in Classic ASP.

Comment: `<!--Other Codes-->` this is not a javascript comment.

Comment: Could I point you towards [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), an excellent site for posting ([SSCCE (Short Self-contained Correct/Compilable Code Examples)](http://sscce.org/)) JavaScript/HTML/CSS code to demonstrate/reproduce problems? If you can post a representative demo, that reproduces your problem, we can try and see what's going on, rather than attempting to parse it in our heads.

Answer (score 1):

The code below resequences as you have described, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/ppd5D/) for a working example.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function () {     
$('.button_remove').click(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var currentName = $(this).attr('name');
    var currentId = getCurrentIdFromName(currentName);

    $('#' + currentId).remove();

    $('#courseTable').find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).each(function() {
            var currentTRId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + currentTRId + ' :input').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var id = getCurrentIdFromName(name);
                var text = name.replace(id,'');
                $(this).attr('name', text + index);             
            });
        });

        $(this).attr('id',index);
        index++;
    });
});
}); 

function getCurrentIdFromName(name) {
var id = name.match(/\d/g);
return id[0];
}
</script>
```

Of course your HTML will need to be like this:

```
<table id="courseTable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr id="0" class="header">
    <td>Course Code</td>
    <td>Course Type</td>
    <td>Index No</td>
    <td>Class Details</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="1">
    <td>
        <select name="NBSCourse1">
            <option selected='selected'>Select Course ID</option>           
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="NBSCourseType1">
            <option selected='selected'>Core</option>           
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="'NBSIndexNo1">
            <option selected='selected'></option>           
            <option value="First">1</option>
            <option value="Second">2</option>
            <option value="Third">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Remove Course" name="btnRemove1" class="button_remove" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
    <td>
        <select name="NBSCourse2">
            <option selected="selected">Select Course ID</option>           
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="NBSCourseType2">
            <option selected="selected">Core</option>           
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="NBSIndexNo2">
            <option selected="selected"></option>           
            <option value="First">1</option>
            <option value="Second">2</option>
            <option value="Third">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Remove Course" name="btnRemove2" class="button_remove" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="3">
    <td>
        <select name="NBSCourse3">
            <option selected='selected'>Select Course ID</option>           
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="NBSCourseType3">
            <option selected='selected'>Core</option>           
            <option value="First">First</option>
            <option value="Second">Second</option>
            <option value="Third">Third</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="NBSIndexNo3">
            <option selected='selected'></option>           
            <option value="First">1</option>
            <option value="Second">2</option>
            <option value="Third">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Remove Course" name="btnRemove3" class="button_remove" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be using something like this:

```
var el = "<tr><td>td1</td><td>td2</td></td>"
$(table).appendChild(el);
```

This will create a table row with a couple of elements, and append it as a child to the table.